# Should I have a NodeJS server for react server-side rendering?

Tags: python, node.js, reactjs

I have a API server which is written in python.
And I wanted to render my react components on server side.
So I searched the best practices and result was having a nodeJS server.

But in my thoughts, this is weird because I have to build a another server with different language. This is bad at maintainable, and maybe have an overload.

So I want to know having nodeJS server is usual. and also how do big companies do server-side rendering.

Comment: What is your API server in? Flask? If so, then the server-side rendering is Jinja2 templates

Comment: @cricket_007 I can imagine write ReactDOM.render in script tag, but this is not server side rendering. is there another way to render on server side?

Comment: Check out https://github.com/nitely/python-react-v8 if want to stick to python only and/or don't want to maintain a Node.js instance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it is as simple as wanting to use Python with React, you can use [python-react](https://github.com/markfinger/python-react) to render React components.

As noted above, if you are using Flask, the templating is in Jinja2, but that isn't necessarily mutually exclusive to using React in your project.

[This resource on using Flask/React](https://realpython.com/blog/python/the-ultimate-flask-front-end/) may be of use to you, as well.

Comment: I checked out this repository before I wrote this question, but this repository uses NodeJS for render. so I wrote this question to know that build a nodejs server for rendering is ideal structure.

Comment: Considering React is a Javascript library, using Javascript (or Node.js, a JS runtime platform) to render it is as intended. My answer, however, was trying to show that you could use wrappers as to not have to manually utilize multiple technologies and instead keep your design and architecture concerned with Python.